# Django prepopulated_fields from command line

Tags: python, django

I am facing a little issue and I can't see through it.

I have a command line that parse a csv file :

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
help = 'Import list of press article from .csv'

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    activate('en') #without it the language will be wrong

    ArticleFile = csv.reader(open(args[0]), delimiter=',')
    global_article = ""
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
    is_new_source = []

    for row in ArticleFile:
        isIn = False
        _country = ""

        if row[0] != "Order":
            if row[7] == "TRUE":
                global_article = True
            elif row[7] == "FALSE":
                _country = Country.objects.get(name_ascii=row[6])
                global_article = False


            if row[5].endswith(' '):
                row[5] = row[5][:-1] 

            for is_exist in is_new_source:
                if is_exist.split(' ') == row[5].split(' '):
                    isIn = True

            new_article = Article(
                article_url=row[9],
                global_regions=global_article,
                title = row[8],
                date_realization=datetime.strptime(row[4] + '-' + row[3] + '-' + row[2], '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
            )

            new_article.save()

            if isIn == False:
                is_new_source.append(row[5])
                _source = ArticleSource.objects.create(name=row[5])
            else:
                _source = ArticleSource.objects.get(name=row[5])
            new_article.sources.add(_source)
            new_article.sites.add(current_site)
            if _country != "":
                new_article.article_country.add(_country)
```

and I have in my admin this magic line (for the source as example):

```
class ArticleSourceAdmin(VersionedPlaceholderAdminMixin,
                       FrontendEditableAdminMixin,
                       SortableAdminMixin):
    list_display = ['__str__']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',), }

admin.site.register(ArticleSource, ArticleSourceAdmin)
```

If I had an article by hand, I can see that the slug is automatically fill while typing.
But with the command line in order to parse the csv file, the slug will stay empty.

Any idea ?

Many thanks

Comment: `prepopulated_fields` use JavaScript to automatically fill the input. Won't work on command line. In order to set `slug` when using command line, you'll need to override your model's `save` method.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you xyres !

Comment: I've posted an answer with an example. See if it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to automatically set `slug` you'll need to override your model's `save` method.

Since you haven't posted your models, I'll try to answer your question with an example:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: P e r f e c t thank you so much or the time saving xyres ;)